# add 2 values together in an ssrs-expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I'm looking to bring in my expression 2 values that I what to add together.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set1", 1, 0) and (Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set", 1, 0))
```

but is just coming back as `0` when the value should be `400` or so.

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how SSRS evaluates your expression

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set1", 1, 0) and (Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set", 1, 0))
```

I think `SUM(1 AND 0)` and `SUM(1 AND 1)` both equal 1.

Your expression needs to be changed a little - though I'm not sure which you need.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set1" OR Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set", 1, 0))
```

Otherwise if you want to count the two different criteria separately, use:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set1", 1, 0) + (Fields!Leadsource.Value = "set", 1, 0))
```

Comment: Now that I look at it again, you use the same field in your comparison so it should be an OR not AND. I updated my answer.